# Extjs 4.2 returns " NetworkError: 404 Not Found " error

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to extjs.I tried to write a simple application with MVC architecture as described here :
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1

When I try to run the application in browser I give this error in firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1/Sample/app/view/userlist.js?_dc=1408194279243"
```

My project structured is :

[image]

List.js file :

```
/**
 * Created by Sina-PC on 8/14/14.
 */
Ext.define('Sample.view.users.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',

    title: 'All Users',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = {
            fields: ['name', 'email'],
            data  : [
                {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
                {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'}
            ]
        };

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Users.js file:

```
Ext.define('Sample.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views:['userlist'],
    init: function() {
        console.log('Initzed Users! This happens before the Application launch function is called');

        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    }
    ,
    onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
});/**
 * Created by Sina-PC on 8/14/14.
 */
```

app.js file :

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sample',
    appFolder:'app',

    controllers:[
        'Users'
    ],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'userlist'
                }
            ]
        });

    }
});
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs doesn't know what is a view 'userlist'. You must add to requires this file.

```
Ext.define('Sample.controller.Users', {

requires: [ 'Sample.view.users.List' ],

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Users.js file has "views:['userlist']," and it should be "views:['Sample.view.users.List'],"